# UIWebView Javascript onclick event not sending event object to function

Tags: javascript, html, ios, uiwebview, dom-events

I am dynamically inserting HTML using simple NSStrings and then loading that into a UIWebview, I am doing this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div onclick=\"MyClickEvent(e);\"....some more text here">
```

and have a function defined like this:

```
function MyClickEvent(e)
{
    //Some other code here
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}
```

The function is never getting called, because of the way the parameter is being passed as e, if I use quotations like this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div onclick=\"MyClickEvent('e');\"....some more text here">
```

Then the function will be called but e is just a simple string as expected, how can I correctly pass the event object?

The HTML at the end simply looks like this:

```
<div onclick="MyClickEvent(e);">
```

which I believe is how it should be, but somehow the event object is not being sent, what am I doing wrong?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work, apparently what you need to do is this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div onclick=\"MyClickEvent(event);\"....some more text here">
```

So simply naming the parameter event, does the trick.